# sphinx SPH_SORT_EXTENDED

Tags: full-text-search, sphinx

Is it possible to sort based on the "weight" and then DESC on attr in the same Query?

For example, if I search for this text "test is fine" and I have this in the index

```
+------------+---------+
| Field      | Type    |
+------------+---------+
| id         | integer |
| text       | field   |
| importance | uint    |
+------------+---------+
```

**importance is attr here**

with these values,

```
1, "test", 3
2, "test is fine", 1
3, "test", 8
```

then if I search for "test is fine" I need the result to be sorted first based on the relevance of the keywords(weight) then based on "importance" attr, so the id output for the search will be

ID result = 2, 3, 1

I'm using this but the result is being sorted based on the attr 'importance' wih no regards to the weight

$cl->SetSortMode( SPH_SORT_ATTR_DESC, 'importance' );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've sort of answered your own question. Yes its SPH_SORT_EXTENDED you want!

```
 $cl->setSortMode(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, "@relevance DESC, importance DESC");
```

Comment: I tried exactly that and it didn't work but I just found out that SetSortMode was overriding the EXTENDED sort